# Architecture for the proper decoupling of OWL/RDF knowledge and (mostly numerical) facts

Tags: architecture, rdf, semantic-web, owl

I am working on an application dealing mainly with public health indicators. The related concepts and knowledge are kept in an OWL ontology. There will also be eventually a (potentially important) number of numerical facts (e.g. indicator for X has value Y), which will grow over time, as more data gets crunched and added to the application. Given that querying this system will imply manipulating concepts (from the ontology), but also (numerical) facts, I am wondering what could be (in broad terms) an ideal data model/storage architecture for it.

I've been contemplating for instance an hybrid architecture where the facts would be stored in a separate SQL database (i.e. using a pure relational model, not a RDF-over-relational one), and for which the querying would be decomposed in two phases: the second (SQL) being derived (or guided) from concepts retrieved from the first (ontology).

As I read however about robust triple stores being able to handle massive amounts of data (billion+ triples), it suggests that I could also try to keep my facts in an RDF store (perhaps implemented with a relational DB). This would have the benefit I suppose of offering a more unified query interface (as I could query simultaneously in the the schema and fact stores using a same API or query engine, instead of mixing SQL in the process as with my hybrid approach). On the other hand, I guess I'd also lose the data crunching capabilities of a relational DB (assuming a triple store is not optimized for operations like aggregation, reduction, etc.) which might be useful in my context.
As a final piece of information, I have already invested some energy in beginning to learn the Jena framework, so I'd appreciate if the suggestions could take it into account.

(I already asked this question on [answers.semanticweb.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20130905073107/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/22172/architecture-for-the-proper-decoupling-of-knowledge-and-mostly-numerical-facts), to no avail.)

Comment: getting into a project about a different field, but similarly involving both easily rdf-able, graph-based social facts w/ large amounts of signal/numerical data. The two -are- very coupled in my case, though, so the inferences need to be based on both the social and numerical. How did putting a bunch of numerical data into RDF work out for you?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like a pure-RDF solution for your application would work.  As you note, RDF databases are maturing quickly, and there are a lot of high-quality open-source and commercial options available.  Most scale well into the billions or tens of billions of triples and support the core semweb standards.

Additionally, many of the options are optimized for a specific set of use cases and scale, so you might try more than one option if you're not happy with the performance of the first.  Also, don't roll your own here, you're not going to slap together something that performs better than even the worst RDF database.  You'll also probably get better performance out of a database that uses native RDF storage rather than something that is backed by a relational db, at least in my experience, that is true.

As for Jena, it's a reasonable framework to use, I personally prefer Sesame, but both are very good to work with.  However, rather than standardizing on Jena (or Sesame), you might be best off standardizing the RDF part of your application, be part or all of it, on SPARQL.  This has the benefit of being database and programming language agnostic.  SPARQL protocol is based on HTTP so you can use pretty much any language out there and be able to talk to the database, and because you're using SPARQL rather than a custom protocol, you can more easily change database as your requirements evolve.  It also makes it easy for others to utilize your data should you wish to make it public, either within your organization or on the web.

SPARQL will give you a powerful query language that is very SQL-like, which includes aggregates (in SPARQL 1.1).  It may not have everything you'll need for your application, you might have to build some custom processing code, but it should give you a good leg to stand on.  RDF databases are optimized for handling SPARQL queries, so no need to worry about performance generally, but SPARQL is PSPACE-complete in terms of complexity, so you *can* write a query that cannot easily be answered.

Finally, while a hybrid architecture would work, my concern would be that longer term that could create undue maintenance burden.  If you're curious about semtech, and think it's a good fit for at least part of your application, you might try with the pure-semtech solution first to see how far you get.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternative to the excellent answer by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479610/michael).

**About his RDF based solution:**

It's possible that the analysis from the metrics will be done with R, so if you go for a full RDF/SPARQL solution you could also consider the [R package for SPARQL](https://code.google.com/p/r-sparql/). You would have here a well integrated and maintainable solution, from the data model straight to the crunching.

**Alternative implementation:**

I think the choice for a semantic web related technology strongly depends on the type of queries you will ask over your data. Are you going to use any reasoning over the ontology? Is it a complicated knowledge base? Are you going to combine these data with other data in the future? Are you planning on releasing the data one day for the public? If yes, then it might be interesting to represent your data in OWL or RDF, so you could take advantage of the expressivity of the language to formulate things you couldn't do with SQL alone and to provide a scaffold to share your information.

If you believe that a SQL query is good enough to retrieve all the data you want, then I would simply store the information in a relational database: It's fast, safe and tested. If the OWL ontology containing the concepts is just a simple vocabulary, you could just store the terms in the database alongside the rest.